# Solving a modified matrix equation using solutions of the original equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to find analytically the eigenmodes of the following equation for a damped system with $N$ degrees of freedom:
$$ \mathbf{M}\ddot{\mathbf{u}} + \mathbf{C} \dot{\mathbf{u}} + \mathbf{K}\mathbf{u} = 0 $$
in terms of the eigenmodes of the undamped system that I have already found computationally:
$$ \mathbf{M}\ddot{\mathbf{u}} + \mathbf{K}\mathbf{u} = 0 $$
These eigenmodes are (say) $ \mathbf{u}_n(t) = \mathbf{u}_n e^{i\omega_n t} $ where
$$ \mathbf{M}^{-1}\mathbf{K}\mathbf{u}_n = \omega_n^2 \mathbf{u}_n $$
$ \mathbf{M}$ is the diagonal mass matrix and $ \mathbf{C}$ is the diagonal matrix of damping factors for each dof. $ \mathbf{K}$ is the symmetric spring constant matrix coupling different degrees of freedom.

**My attempt so far:** Assuming the time dependence as $\mathbf{u}(t) = \mathbf{u}e^{i\omega t}$, the damped equation can be written as:
$$  (\mathbf{M}^{-1}\mathbf{K} + i\omega\mathbf{M}^{-1}\mathbf{C})\mathbf{u} = \omega^2 \mathbf{u} $$
Now since $\mathbf{C}$ is not proportional to the Identity matrix, it does not commute with the "dynamical" matrix $\mathbf{M}^{-1}\mathbf{K}$ and so the previously found normal modes are not the eigenmodes for the new system. But is it possible to maybe rescale some of the degrees of freedom or transform the equation in another way and find the new normal modes using the old ones $\mathbf{u}_n$?

Also, note that I wish to look at the solutions for low frequencies, so treating the damping as a small perturbation does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving the non-linear eigenvalue problem as posed above in the third equation presents difficulties, so we will transform the problem using a classic trick to obtain the eigenmodes. Note that this equation can be written as a first order system of equations in the variables $(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{p}:=\mathbf{\dot{u}})$. Under the additional assumption that $M$ is an invertible matrix we can write the system in the following form

$$\frac{d}{dt}\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{u}\\\mathbf{p}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0_n&\mathbb{I_n}\\-M^{-1}K&-M^{-1}C\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{u}\\\mathbf{p}\end{pmatrix}$$

Applying a Fourier transform to this equation shows that the eigenmodes and eigenfrequencies can be found  as the solution to the eigenproblem of the augmented $2n\times 2n$ matrix

$$R:=\begin{pmatrix}0_n&\mathbb{I_n}\\-M^{-1}K&-M^{-1}C\end{pmatrix}$$

$$R\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{\hat{u}}(\omega)\\\hat{\mathbf{p}}(\omega)\end{pmatrix}=i\omega\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{\hat{u}}(\omega)\\\hat{\mathbf{p}}(\omega)\end{pmatrix}$$

One can easily see that this formalism reproduces the known eigenmodes for $n=1$, and that generally the eigenvalues are complex.